# Remotely find git commit and tag info on a branch

Tags: git

Is it possible to determine SHA values and Git tags remotely i.e without cloning git repo?

I want to determine if there is n commits happened to the repo and then trigger a job. However, cloning each repo or maintaining one will be time consuming.

Answer (score 3):

You can get *some* of the information you want with `git ls-remote`.  This has your Git call up some other Git and ask the other Git to list *its* branch and tag names, and the corresponding hash IDs.

Your subject line asks for:

> git commit and tag info on a branch

but this phrase is ill-formed.  "Tag info", in particular—whatever you mean by that phrase—is *never* "on a branch"; at most, a tag name *coincides* with a branch name, or the tagged object is *reachable from* one or more branch names.  Since one commit can be on dozens of branches, it's not unusual for a tag name to identify a commit that is on<sup>1</sup> multiple branches.

A *branch name* is a name whose fully-spelled-out form starts with `refs/heads/`: for instance, branch `master` is really `refs/heads/master`.  A *tag name* is a name whose fully-spelled-out form starts with `refs/tags/`: for instance, tag `v2.1` is really `refs/tags/v2.1`.  The `git ls-remote` command has their Git tell your Git their full names—so the ones with `refs/heads/` are their branch names, for instance—and their corresponding hash IDs.

Each name just holds *one* hash ID.  Two different names can hold two different hash IDs, or the same hash ID.

Branch names are constrained: they always hold the hash ID of some existing, valid commit.  Tag names often hold the hash ID of an *annotated tag object* rather than that of a commit.  When a tag name holds the hash ID of a tag object, you'll get *two* output lines.  Here is a snippet of output from `git ls-remote`:

```
274b9cc25322d9ee79aa8e6d4e86f0ffe5ced925        refs/heads/master
...
74d2a8cf12bf102a8cedaf66736503bb3fe88dfb        refs/tags/v2.2.0
b260d265e189728b26e50506ac6ffab6a7d588da        refs/tags/v2.2.0^{}
3fabc04268de1cec1628265810769e33dae44cd8        refs/tags/v2.2.0-rc0
4ace7ff4557350b7e0b57d024a2ea311b332e01d        refs/tags/v2.2.0-rc0^{}
```

This tells us that their Git's `master` identifies commit `274b9cc25322d9ee79aa8e6d4e86f0ffe5ced925`.  Their Git's `v2.2.0` identifies tag object `74d2a8cf12bf102a8cedaf66736503bb3fe88dfb` which in turn identifies another object, in this case `b260d265e189728b26e50506ac6ffab6a7d588da`.

It's not possible to tell from this alone what the type of object `b260d265e189728b26e50506ac6ffab6a7d588da` is, but in fact it's a commit.  (To find that out, we have that Git transfer the objects to our Git and then use `git cat-file -t`.)

> I want to determine if there is n commits happened to the repo ...

If *n* here stands for a *number*, you can't do that: counting commits requires that you *have* the commits.

If *n* here stands for *new*, you can't *quite* do that.  Suppose you find that they have a branch name *B* that identifies commit *C1* right now.  Tomorrow, you query their repository and find that they have branch name *B* but it identifies commit *C2* right now.  You can tell that the branch name has moved, but you do not know for certain that it moved "forwards" to have *new* commits.  It may have moved "backwards" to discard commits, or "sideways" so that some old commits are gone and some new commits are now reachable.

> cloning each repo or maintaining one will be time consuming ...

Cloning a repository can take a while, depending on your network speed.  In most cases, though, *updating* a clone is quite fast, especially if the clone is one made with `--bare` or `--mirror` so that there is no work-tree to update.  Hence this is usually the way to go.

Some build systems do a fresh clone each time but use *shallow* clones to avoid bringing over most objects.  This can be a successful method of dealing with otherwise large repositories.

---

<sup>1</sup>I use the phrase *on a branch* here in the sense that the commit is reachable from the branch tip, as identified by that branch name.  Another way to describe this is that the commit is *contained in* the branch.  For much more on this subject, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).